# Refactoring XSD Schemas

Tags: xml, refactoring, xsd

I'm working in a project which needs to clean up some third party XSD Schemas and I want to do some refactoring of common elements in them.

There is any suitable tool to automate this? I tried by sfactor from XMLBeans but it doesn't work (it throws a weird exception which even Google can't answer!).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With lack of answers, I pulled out some spare time and I build [xnikt](http://code.google.com/p/xnikt/), a Java tool which fulfills my actual need to extract common elements from XSD. I free it as GPL, so anyone can fork it, enhance it, etc.

I'm open to collaboration, so if anyone has ideas and time, contact me!

And I tested it against the XSD schemas which I wanted to refactor and it works like a charm.

I hope it would help anyone who maybe is or will be in the same situation.